# How to divide a circle into three equal parts with HTML5 canvas?

Tags: html, math, canvas, geometry, 2d-context-api

[image]

How can I divide a circle into three equal parts with HTML5 canvas 2D context API like above figure?

I was trying [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mithun/V8xms/)

Can somebody suggest a better way? probably with percentages (or in degrees) instead of hard-coded coordinates?

```
var can = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillStyle = "#BD1981";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(200, 200, 150, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();

ctx.strokeStyle = "#FFC8B2";
ctx.lineWidth = "2";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(200, 200);
ctx.lineTo(100, 100);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(200, 200);
ctx.lineTo(350, 200);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(200, 200);
ctx.lineTo(100, 300);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: What are the "percentages" supposed to represent?

Comment: like 33% (100/3) or 120 degree (360/3)

Comment: And what if I was to use 35%?

Comment: First, learn basic trigonometry...

Comment: Btw, your lines don't divide the circle into three equal parts!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here is a function (demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/eLdCA/3/) that allows you to specify a starting point, the length and the angle in degrees:

```
var drawAngledLine = function(x, y, length, angle) {
    var radians = angle / 180 * Math.PI;
    var endX = x + length * Math.cos(radians);
    var endY = y - length * Math.sin(radians);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x, y)
    ctx.lineTo(endX, endY);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Putting it all together (using @phant0m's `drawAngledLine`):

```
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var RADIUS = 70;

function drawCircle(x, y, r) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
}

function drawAngledLine(x, y, length, angle) {
    var radians = angle / 180 * Math.PI;
    var endX = x + length * Math.cos(radians);
    var endY = y - length * Math.sin(radians);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x, y)
    ctx.lineTo(endX, endY);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
}

drawCircle(140, 140, RADIUS);
drawAngledLine(140, 140, RADIUS, 1 * (360 / 3));
drawAngledLine(140, 140, RADIUS, 2 * (360 / 3));
drawAngledLine(140, 140, RADIUS, 3 * (360 / 3));
```

Demo here:

- http://jsfiddle.net/My8eX/

Answer (score 0):

I know you probably got your answer but I found Wayne's jsfiddle helpful so I'm adding my contribution which lets you set a custom number of sections you want to divide the circle into.

http://jsfiddle.net/yorksea/3ef0y22c/2/

(also using @phant0m's drawAngledLine)

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var RADIUS = 300;
var num_sections = 19; //set this for number of divisions

function drawCircle(x, y, r) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function drawAngledLine(x, y, length, angle) {
  var radians = angle / 180 * Math.PI;
  var endX = x + length * Math.cos(radians);
  var endY = y - length * Math.sin(radians);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x, y)
  ctx.lineTo(endX, endY);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
}

//draw circle outline
drawCircle(320, 320, RADIUS);

//loop the number of sections to draw each
for (i = 1; i <= num_sections; i++) {
  drawAngledLine(320, 320, RADIUS, i * (360 / num_sections));
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="650" height="650"></canvas>
```